# How can I define the nearest matched in regex?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my string:

```
$str = "somethingtestsomethingtestsomething123something
        somethingtestsomethingtestsomething123something
        somethingtestsomethingtestsomething123something
        somethingtestsomethingtestsomething123something";
```

And this is my pattern:

```
/test.*?123/
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/YoRuuA/2)

**Current result:** `testsomethingtestsomething123`, `$1` equals `somethingtestsomething`

**Expected result:** `testsomething123`, `$1` equals `something`

As you see I want to match everything between the nearest `test` to `123` and `123`. How can I do that?

Comment: it's trivial to extract the expected result from the current result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lazy quantifier doesn't necessarily give you the shortest possible match - only the shortest possible match starting from the leftmost position in the string that matches.

You need to use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that none of the delimiters may be part of the "between" text:

```
/test(?:(?!test|123).)*123/
```

Comment: Doesn't it? It seems to work for me. Or are you referring to group `$1` which isn't defined in either your or my regex?

Comment: I missed the `g` flag in the fiddle, yes it works perfectly, thank you, uptove

Comment: I edited my pattern you remove the lazy quantifier and instead adding the ending delimiter to the lookahead. Looks a bit clearer to me.

Comment: look, your answer is great, but sadly I cannot apply in on my real content, [Here](https://regex101.com/r/N1j4De/33) my real content. Currently, it has 2 matches. The first one is correct, but the second one should start from [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkmo8.png). Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: @stack: That content is vastly different from what you posted in your question. It's nice to simplify the problem, but not too much - for example, your content contains nested brackets, something that is inherently problematic for regexes. I can't adjust the regex for that and still answer your original question. Perhaps better "re-ask" your actual question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most probably, regex is not the solution to that problem.